# Does the meaning of $dx^2$ in $(\frac{dy}{dx^2})$ and $(\frac{d^2y}{dx^2})$ differ

Tags: calculus

Am I right in thinking that in $\frac{dy}{dx^2}$ (The derivative of y with respect to $x^2$), $dx^2$ means $d(x^2)$, while in $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}$, $dx^2$ means $(dx)^2$?

That what is on top of the bar($\frac{ }{ }$) determines the meaning of $dx^2$?

Comment: $dx^2$ means $d(d(x))$, not $d(x^2)$. So both $dx^2$ are same I think.

Comment: @AnikBhowmick - if your interpretation were correct then $\frac{dy}{dx^2}$ might not be meaningful

Comment: Indeed "$\frac{dy}{dx^2}$" looks particularly confusing.  Write "$\frac{dy}{dz}$ where $z=x^2$" instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to have encountered a case of rather confusing notation.

*If* $y=y(x^2)$ is a function of $x^2$, you can of course differentiate it with respect to the argument. However, you should write that as 
$$\frac{\text{d} y}{\text{d}\!\left(x^2\right)}\quad \text{or} \quad \frac{\text{d} y(x^2)}{\text{d}\!\left(x^2\right)}\quad \text{or} \quad \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}\!\left(x^2\right)} \, y(x^2) $$
precisely to avoid the confusion you mentioned. Writing just $\text d x^2$  in the denominator is bound to lead to misunderstandings, in particular if the argument of the function is not given and you would assume it to be $y(x)$.

On the other hand, in $\frac{\text d^2y}{\text d x^2}$, you should not think of numertaor and denominator as separate entities, but rather consider the expression as 
$$\frac{\text d}{\text d x}\left(\frac{\text d}{\text d x}\,y\right)=\left(\frac{\text d}{\text d x}\right)^2 y\,,$$
i.e. the square of the derivative operator $\frac{\text d}{\text d x}$ acting of the funtion $y$, which presumably is intended as $y(x)$.